# How to adjust row and column position in pandas crosstab?

Tags: python, pandas

I have data to show with pandas crosstab, and I want the result will be like this

[image: Result that i want]

The image above is easy to read. When I use pandas, it automatically order the column and row.

```
headers = ["rejection", "age"]
df = pd.read_csv("tooth.txt", header=None, names=headers, na_values="?" )

pd.crosstab(df.rejection, df.age)
```

[image]

Is there a way to adjust the position of row and column to make it easier to read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to `reindex` the columns and rows according to your desired order:

```
#reorder columns
df = df.reindex(['Under20', '20to25', '25to30', '30to35', '35to40', 'Over40'], 
     axis="columns")

#reorder rows
df = df.reindex(['Yes', 'No'])
```

Or you can combine these steps in one line:

```
df = df.reindex(['Under20', '20to25', '25to30', '30to35', '35to40', 'Over40'], 
     axis="columns").reindex(['Yes', 'No'])
```

Comment: Thanks, its work. But is it possible to still show it with pd.crosstab()? I use print(df) to make it work. I try to reindex it, than using pd.crosstab(), it does not work

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to add spaces in text values of *age* column, and convert
them from plain *string* (*object*) to an **ordered** category:

```
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype
ageCat = CategoricalDtype(ordered=True,
    categories=['Under 20', '20 to 25', '25 to 30', '30 to 35', '35 to 40', 'Over 40'])
df.age = df.age.map({'Under20': 'Under 20', '20to25': '20 to 25',
    '25to30': '25 to 30', '30to35': '30 to 35', '35to40': '35 to 40',
    'Over40': 'Over 40'}).astype(ageCat)
```

The second step is your *crosstab*:

```
res = pd.crosstab(df.rejection, df.age)
```

Then you should change the index name and revert its sort order:

```
res.index.name = 'Rejected'
res.sort_index(ascending=False, inplace=True)
```

And the last step is to change column names:

```
res.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Age (years)'], res.columns], names=None)
```

The final result, with numeric values takes from my test data, is:

```
         Age (years)                                            
            Under 20 20 to 25 25 to 30 30 to 35 35 to 40 Over 40
Rejected                                                        
Yes                1        3        2        2        3       3
No                 2        2        3        3        6       6
```